# Old Session Data being alerted after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I have an AJAX call that updates a `$_SESSION` variable, after that the `<script>` should echo out the new variable. The data is reaching the .php page, and also is being stored into the session. But it's alerting the old data after the AJAX call.
I've tried using `setTimeout` and also tried moving the call that alerts the new variable outside of the `AJAX` success call. I still get the same result.

Why isn't it alerting the new `$_SESSION` data?

**AJAX**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#sendBtn').click(function() {                
        var theva = $("#element_23").val();                                 
         $.ajax({
         type   : "POST",
         url    :'check.php',
         data   : {theva : theva},
         success: function() {
             setTimeout(function() {
             var theva2 = "<? echo $_SESSION['disp'];?>";
             alert(theva2);},3000);}                        
         });                                
    });     
});
</script>
```

**check.php**

```
<? 
if($_POST){
$_SESSION['disp'] = $_POST['theva'];}
?>
```

Comment: Avoid use of shorthand tags.

Comment: View the page source, what do you see? Learn about the page lifecycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var theva2 = "<? echo $_SESSION['disp'];?>";
```

This line contains php code, that will only get rendered on page load. If you refresh the page and view the source you will see i has updated.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this is a logic errer

EDIT as per your comment

You can return the value from check.php:

```
<? 
if($_POST){
    $_SESSION['disp'] = $_POST['theva'];
    echo 'Session value is now: '.$_SESSION['disp'];
}
?>
```

And alter your js success function to alert the data:

```
success: function(data) {

         alert(data);

     });
```

Comment: is it possible to alert the value of the new session variable without a page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP is rendered at the server. When you load the page containing the AJAX request, the PHP code is interpreted and `theva2` will then contain your session variable.

You might change it afterwards, but because the main page (containing the AJAX code) is never reloaded, it will still show the old value (because it's rendered server-side when you load the page, not when you make your AJAX request).

Comment: is it possible to alert the value of the new session variable without a page refresh?

Comment: You could add it as the response of your `check.php` file, so the AJAX  call will be able to retrieve that response. However, I do not see the purpose of doing so, be cause you already know that your session value will contain the `theva` variable (because that's the original parameter).